# JavaFX 2: Draggable popup tool window?

Tags: popup, draggable, javafx-2, stage

I'd like to make a draggable popup control, which is independent of its parent Window, and does not have the system's title bar.

I tried is to rewrite the JavaFx example for draggable panels in order to move an undecorated stage based on mouse events on a node, see code below. Unfortunately this doesn't seem to work properly, it's not smooth and jumps around the screen erratically for multiple screens. I read that some others used similar methods, however is this the only way to do this currently or did anyone find a nice solution ?
Thanks,

```
private Node makeDraggable(final Node node) {
    final DragContext dragContext = new DragContext();
    final Node wrapGroup = node;

    wrapGroup.addEventFilter(
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_PRESSED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                        dragContext.mouseAnchorX = mouseEvent.getX();
                        dragContext.mouseAnchorY = mouseEvent.getY();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateX =
                                stage.getX();
                        dragContext.initialTranslateY =
                                stage.getY();
                    }

            });

    wrapGroup.addEventFilter(
            MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED,
            new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                public void handle(final MouseEvent mouseEvent) {

                        stage.setX(
                                dragContext.initialTranslateX
                                        + mouseEvent.getX()
                                        - dragContext.mouseAnchorX);
                        stage.setY(
                                dragContext.initialTranslateY
                                        + mouseEvent.getY()
                                        - dragContext.mouseAnchorY);
                    dragContext.initialTranslateX =
                            stage.getX();
                    dragContext.initialTranslateY =
                            stage.getY();

                }
            });

    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used this sample method below when making a [clock](https://gist.github.com/3388637).

I've only tested it on one screen, because I don't have multiple screens available.

```
/** holder structure for drag delta amounts */
private static class Delta { double x, y; }

/** makes a stage draggable using a given node */
public static void makeDraggable(final Stage stage, final Node byNode) {
    final Delta dragDelta = new Delta();
    byNode.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            // record a delta distance for the drag and drop operation.
            dragDelta.x = stage.getX() - mouseEvent.getScreenX();
            dragDelta.y = stage.getY() - mouseEvent.getScreenY();
            byNode.setCursor(Cursor.MOVE);
        }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseReleased(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            byNode.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            stage.setX(mouseEvent.getScreenX() + dragDelta.x);
            stage.setY(mouseEvent.getScreenY() + dragDelta.y);
        }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                byNode.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
            }
        }
    });
    byNode.setOnMouseExited(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
        @Override public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
            if (!mouseEvent.isPrimaryButtonDown()) {
                byNode.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Just one more thing, do you also have a makeResizable? Or could you tell me where this was found, Thanks!

Comment: I wrote it.  I have not written a corresponding resize function - take a look at the [ensemble app source](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/samples/index.html) for that.

Comment: There is a missing part in your copied example for it to work:
`private static class Delta {
    double x, y;
}`

Comment: Thanks, Pony I added the additional `Delta` definition to the code snippet embedded in the answer.

Comment: A nice alternative to `MOVE` and `HAND`, here, is `CLOSED_HAND` and `OPEN_HAND`. Then you get the "grabbing" effect. Wonderful as always, @jewelsea.